# Spawn Python subprocess (async?) on Nginx reverse proxy response return

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi

I have an Nginx which acts as a reverse proxy for an upstream web service.
I use it to cache some results -  mainly to reduce my upstream costs.
I want to get the results back to the client/browser/requestor ASAP, however, as a secondary endeavour, I also want to use Python to process the response.
This processing will take some seconds; and I certainly don't want to make the requestor wait.
So can I send the upstream response back to the requestor immediately, but also shart a Python subprocess(?) for processing the response?  (And what is the most performant way of doing that?   WSGI?)
I guess I'm wondering if the undocumented post_action can execute asynchronously